# How can I find the definition of a built-in type like `RegExpExecArray`?

Tags: typescript

In the following code, the variable `x` has the type `RegExpExecArray | null` (according to VSCode).

```
  const storeIdRegExp = /s(?<storeId>\d+)/u;
  const x = storeIdRegExp.exec(query);
```

**How can I find the definition of `RegExpExecArray`? I couldn't find it documented anywhere.**

---

Note: I did find a couple of references in the TypeScript source code, particularly [1.0lib-noErrors.js](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/663b19fe4a7c4d4ddaa61aedadd28da06acd27b6/tests/baselines/reference/1.0lib-noErrors.js#L794-L824) and [lib.es2018.regexp.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/663b19fe4a7c4d4ddaa61aedadd28da06acd27b6/lib/lib.es2018.regexp.d.ts#L27-L31) (which I assume applies if the compilation target is ES2018+). But that wasn't easy to find and I'm not 100% sure the union of these interfaces is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write

```
let x: RegExpExecArray
```

and then use the "Go to definition" command (ctrl+click)

Then the editor will show you all the pieces of its definition:

```
// lib.es2018.regexp.d.ts
interface RegExpExecArray {
    groups?: {
        [key: string]: string
    }
}
// lib.es2015.d.ts
interface RegExpExecArray extends Array<string> {
    /**
     * The index of the search at which the result was found.
     */
    index: number;
    /**
     * A copy of the search string.
     */
    input: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only TypeScript-specific APIs will be documented by [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/). The example you referenced are non-TypeScript APIs, therefore there are no official TypeScript documentation.

You will have to find the documentation from its respective sources. For example, `RegExp.prototype.exec` is a JavaScript API, therefore you should find its documentation from [ECMAScript](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.2) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

The type references that you mentioned, like [`RegExpExecArray`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L946) and many others, are maintained [in TypeScript repo](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/tree/main/lib), and some other extensions from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped), but they serve only as references to the official documentation.

Comment: OP is asking for *Type definitions*.